# How can I use HTML tags in my AddContact.js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new at React. I just try to learn but I got an error. My target is make a simple page site with react. My header.js file is fine. But I got an error in my AddContact.js file. I didn't understand why I got this error. I need help about it. If you need another information about question please let me know.

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/components/AddContact.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /home/tayyipcanbay/Desktop/contact-app/src/components/AddContact.js: Unexpected token (6:12)

  4 |     render(){
  5 |         return{
> 6 |             <div>
    |             ^
  7 |                 Test Message
  8 |             </div>
  9 |         };
    at instantiate (/home/tayyipcanbay/Desktop/contact-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:72:32)
    at constructor (/home/tayyipcanbay/Desktop/contact-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:366:12)
    at FlowParserMixin.raise (/home/tayyipcanbay/Desktop/contact-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3453:19)
    at FlowParserMixin.unexpected (/home/tayyipcanbay/Desktop/contact-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3491:16)
    at FlowParserMixin.parsePropertyName (/home/tayyipcanbay/Desktop/contact-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:13991:24)
    at FlowParserMixin.parsePropertyDefinition (/home/tayyipcanbay/Desktop/contact-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:13823:22)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseObjectLike (/home/tayyipcanbay/Desktop/contact-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:13743:21)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseExprAtom (/home/tayyipcanbay/Desktop/contact-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:13135:23)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseExprAtom (/home/tayyipcanbay/Desktop/contact-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8174:20)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseExprSubscripts (/home/tayyipcanbay/Desktop/contact-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12785:23)


ERROR

[eslint] 
src/components/AddContact.js
  Line 6:12:  Parsing error: Unexpected token (6:12)
```

[Here is my error as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RF9r.png)

My AddContact.js file

```
import React from "react";

class AddContact extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return{
            <div>
                Test Message
            </div>
        };
    }
}   
export default AddContact;
```

My Header.js file:

```
import React from "react";

const Header=()=>{
    return(
        <div className="ui fixed menu">
            <div className="ui container center">
                <h2>Contact Manager </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Header;
```

My App.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import AddContact from './AddContact';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <AddContact />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './components/App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `{}` to `()`

```js
import React from "react";

class AddContact extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return ( // Changed
            <div>
                Test Message
            </div>
        ) // Changed
    }
}   
export default AddContact;
```

Comment: It worked thank you. It was really easy thats my bad. Sorry for taking your time and thanks for fast reply.

Answer (score 1):

Use `(` instead of `{`

```
  return (
        <div>
            Test Message
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: It worked thank you. It was really easy thats my bad. Sorry for taking your time and thanks for fast reply.

Answer (score 0):

Change it like so, return should not return an object, just the html.

```
import React from "react";

class AddContact extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                Test Message
            </div>
        );
    }
}   
export default AddContact;
```

Comment: It worked thank you. It was really easy thats my bad. Sorry for taking your time and thanks for fast reply.

Comment: @stabakunin it's ok All the best learning react :)